# Android: Service is stopped when clearing ram storage

Tags: android, service

I have coded a simple app in Android Studio. What it does is not important but it starts a Service with `Context.startService(Intent i)`. Till now everything is allright BUT when I kill all tasks with my Task Manager of my phone the Service is killed, too and with it the notification ist creates! I don't understand why.

By the way: I used `return START_STICKY` at the end of my Service. And it has been started/sheduled by the Timer class with `Timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(TimerTask task, int delay, int period)`. The Service has been started by my Main Application or by the BroadcastReceiver which received `BOOT_COMPLETED`. The timer has also not been canceled.

Hope you will pardon my english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Services that are started with startService does not stop until an explicit call - stopService is done on that particular service. Another case when the service stops is when the phone needs more memory its stops the background services and applications. In your case, you are doing the exact same thing. Clicking on the kill all tasks clears the memory which is the exact thing that happens when phone is out of memory and wants more memory. In that case - services are stopped and sticky services are restarted. Now, how to handle the restart of the service properly, kindly search **clearing memory stops services android** and you will be shown a bunch of answers on stackoverflow !